# Database Table very slow after delete

Tags: mysql, database, google-app-engine, innodb

I have a MySQL InnoDB database running on the Google App-Engine.
One of the tables has the current date and a user_id as primary key stored with some additional data.
The table had around 7 million rows and I deleted 6 million of them with a DELETE query. Since that any query using this table is much slower than before.

Any ideas what could cause this behavior or how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you need to do the delete again, see [_Big deletes_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/big-deletes/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After such a massive delete on innodb you would better to use [OPTIMISE table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html) statement

> Use OPTIMIZE TABLE in these cases, depending on the type of table:
>
> - After doing substantial insert, update, or delete operations on an    InnoDB table that has its own .ibd file because it was created with
>     the innodb_file_per_table option enabled. The table and indexes are
>     reorganized, and disk space can be reclaimed for use by the operating 
>     system.
> - After doing substantial insert, update, or delete operations on    columns that are part of a FULLTEXT index in an InnoDB table. Set the 
>     configuration option innodb_optimize_fulltext_only=1 first. To keep
>     the index maintenance period to a reasonable time, set the
>     innodb_ft_num_word_optimize option to specify how many words to
>     update in the search index, and run a sequence of OPTIMIZE TABLE
>     statements until the search index is fully updated.

Prior to optimize, check the table's state using [ANALYSE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/check-table.html), and it's indexes using [SHOW INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-index.html). These instructions will provide you with information regarding the "flaws" that OPTIMIZE can fix.

All this is easy to do in phpmyadmin.